# What do I do? I need help, I am a new user!

Tags: discussion, on-hold

It's really annoying that the first question I asked got put on hold for being 'not appropriate'. I know that it wasn't really the best Stack Exchange community to ask it in, but I really had no other choice. There was nowhere else to put it, and that community was the closest one. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: What was the question? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: "What should I do" -- ask a new question, this time one that is on-topic, or perhaps answer something? Why are you asking, is there something you haven't told us?

Comment: If there isn't an appropriate site for it, don't ask it. But perhaps it helps if you could show us the particular questions. Maybe that allows us to provide more specific advice.

Comment: Sorry, the sites are not there to ask just any question. If a question doesn't fit, **don't ask it**. The model of these sites works because we are strict as to what goes and what doesn't.

Comment: Start sentences with uppercase and always use uppercase "I". Well-written posts are a good start.

Comment: And spend more time writing titles that actually tell the reader what your question is.  "I'm new and need help" tells the reader nothing about that question, beyond the fact that the reader doesn't know how to write a title and that they should probably stay away.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question)

Answer (score 7):

You should figure out what you need to do in order to make your question appropriate.  If you need help doing this, after having looked through the introductory material on how to ask an appropriate question, you can post about it on the relevant meta site for help improving the question.

If your question simply cannot be made to be appropriate on any SE site, because there are no sites where it is on topic, then you'll need to find somewhere besides this network to ask your question.

Answer (score 3):

One approach that worked great for me is **lurking.** I lurked on Stack Overflow for quite a while before I submitted my first post. Just to be clear here, lurking does not mean reading the site only when you are searching for an answer to a problem. It means picking a few tags as favorites (preferably *not* low traffic tags, because I don't think they give a good idea of the dynamics of a site) and reading on a daily basis the questions and answers that are posted in these tags. See how they are received by the community. **Learn from other people's mistakes.**

There's only so much that reading the help can tell you.